# android tiled map technique

Tags: java, android, dictionary, tiles

I want to re-create google-maps like functionality (map interface which can be scrolled, zoomed in/out, scaling and multiple levels) but for my own map, using locally stored (on SD card) set of tiles. What I have is a set of tiles for every map level. There are about 6-8 levels of the map. 
So what I was thinking, if there's already an engine or smth that can do all that for me, given a set of images and level configuration.

Otherwise it seems like my only option is to write it from scratch. So if anyone has any idea about existing component/solution, would appreaciate advice.

Comment: You might have some luck by searching for deep zoom, image pryamids, and multiscale images.

Comment: have you found this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576068/tiled-map-on-android