# tiled map on android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, tile

I want to implement an offline map of an area(city size), I need to use tiled map with several zoom levels and be able to zoom in/out by pinching on the map, double tap, pan and so on. I don't want to use OpenStreetmap. The map I use is a transit map, so it is very different from openstreetmap. I have tools to cut the map into tiles.

I wonder if there is any free library that I can use, I know this question has been asked(like [android tiled map technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695359/android-tiled-map-technique)) but I could not find an acceptable answer.

I am aware of the mAppWidget, but it is too expensive. Would appreciate any help or hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up buying a library called mAppWidget from here: http://mapp.android-libraries.com

It is pretty cool library and worth the money.

Answer (score 3):

There's a complete list of open-source map engines [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android). [OSMand](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/) is one of the most popular.  It'd be worth your time to get familiar with the [Openstreetmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/) site; you can get your offline tiles from there as well.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is I don't want to use OpenStreetmap. The map I use is a transit map, so it is very different from openstreetmap. I have tools to cut the map into tiles.